# My code only has six lines but fails at line 7 "Unexpected end of input"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to set up an extension that will highlight the comments on a particular website. All comments are within a specific class. This is as far as I've come so far:

```
console.log("It works");

let paragraphs = document.getElementsByClassName('sc-fAJaQT dGfKUv');
for (elt of paragraphs) {
  elt.style['background-color'] = '#FF00FF';
}
```

However, chrome keeps throwing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" I don't understand how and why. All parentheses and curly brackets should be alright?

Comment: Make sure to save the file in UTF-8 encoding with BOM or specify the UTF8 encoding in your html file using `<meta>` tag, also maybe on your `<script>` tag.

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using? Is that the entire content of the file? Can you show its exact bytes using `xxd` or something?

Comment: I'm currently using Version 76.0.3809.100 on Mac OS 10.13.4 
So far that's the only content. I haven't come any further 'cause it keeps causing this error. @wOxxOm It's already encoded in UTF8.

Comment: backgroundColor

Comment: @George this didn't change anything.

Comment: ok but if you get it working, it's still not background-color

Comment: you need to put let before elt

Comment: @George Thanks for your input. I've tried it with "let" and "backgroundColor" but this didn't solve it.

Comment: sorry I've never made a chrome extension before, but just looking at a tutorial it looks like you need to set up some infrastructure beforehand. See: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Comment: @lonesomeclicker my suggestion was much more than just saving in UTF8... and it's based on similar cases I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

One way to change a css property of an element is like this:
`elem.style.property = '';`

In your case you are changing the background color. You can do that like this:
`elem.style.backgroundColor = '#FF00FF';`

A working example, that changes some buttons on StackOverflow to have purple backgrounds is shown below with your fixed code.

```
console.log("It works");

var paragraphs = document.getElementsByClassName('s-btn');
for (elt of paragraphs) {
  elt.style.backgroundColor = '#FF00FF';
}
```